# Bootstrap Select Live Search Works on one computer, not another

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-selectpicker

Can anyone explain why Bootstrap Select Live Search would work on one computer, but not another? I'm accessing the same web page from two different Windows 7 computers both running the same version of Brave browser.

My PC:

[image: My PC - Works]

My colleague's PC:

[image]

I pulled up the developer tools on my colleague's PC and I don't see any errors in the console.